# Run ScalaTest tests in parallel

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

Given the following test suite:

```
class ParallelizeMe extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  override def beforeAll() = println("before")              
  override def afterAll()  = println("after")               

  test("test 1") {                                          
    println("1a")
    Thread.sleep(3000)                                      
    println("1b")                                           
  }

  test("test 2") {                                          
    println("2a")
    Thread.sleep(1000)                                      
    println("2b")
  }

}
```

How can I run the tests (via sbt) in parallel?  Ideally, I want the order of execution to produce the following on stdout:

```
before
1a
2a
2b
1b
after
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `ParallelTestExecution` and a `-P` command-line argument to the `Runner` to make them run in parallel:

```
import org.scalatest.{ParallelTestExecution, BeforeAndAfterAll, FunSuite}
class ParallelizableSpec extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll with ParallelTestExecution {
   ...
}
```

Note that -P is required. From the source:

> If you include `-P` on the command line, `Runner` will pass a
> `Distributor` to the `Suite`s you specify with `-s`. `Runner` will set
> up a thread pool to execute any `Suite`s passed to the `Distributor`'s
> `put` method in parallel.

It will also run the tests in isolation, so `before` and `after` will be run in each thread. See more in the docs for [ParallelTestExecution](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.12/org/scalatest/ParallelTestExecution.html) and [Runner](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.12/org/scalatest/tools/Runner$.html).

In SBT, to use the flag, add this to `build.sbt`:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-P")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.  I wish I could have beforeAll and afterAll run only once each, but this is close enough.  For reference, I added this to my *build.sbt*: `testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-P")`

Comment: Any idea how to use the `-c` option to change the number of threads?

Comment: Doesn't seem to help; I see 8 tests running at a time.  Is `-PN` documented somewhere?

Comment: On Runner page: http://www.artima.com/docs-scalatest-2.0.M2/org/scalatest/tools/Runner%24.html

Comment: FYI: with sbt 0.13 you cannot use -P option. sbt will handle parallel execution itself automatically.

Comment: This was so much more helpful than the scalatest docs!  Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to run only a select few tests in parallel and let the others follow a sequential order?