# Run Play ScalaTest via SBT in Parallel

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

My `Test.scala` has 2 tests that I'd like to run in parallel.

> > C:/users/Kevin/workspace/playApp> sbt test

```
class ConcurrentRequests extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll with ParallelTestExecution {
  val start = System.nanoTime()

  test("foo") {
     println("foo")
     foo        
     println("foo in " + (System.nanoTime - start) / 1000000000 + " seconds.")
  }

  test("bar") {
     println("bar")
     bar        
     println("bar in " + (System.nanoTime - start) / 1000000000 + " seconds.")
  }
}
```

I tried this [post's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752681/run-scalatest-tests-in-parallel) answers, namely adding `testOptions` to my `$PLAY_APP/build.sbt`, as well as using the `-P` option, but neither worked. I say it didn't work since **"foo"** printed out, executed its calls, and then bar printed out and executed **after**.

How can I run this Play test in parallel via sbt?

**EDIT**

As a work-around, I put the first test in **ConcurrentTest.scala** and the second in a separate **ConcurrentTest2.scala** file. And then ScalaTest ran the tests in parallel. From a maintenance point-of-view, I'd rather have a single test file and then run each of them in parallel.