# How to make SBT run test suites in parallel?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I have a bunch of integration tests running by sbt, given test N suites with 1..M tests per each suite. 
I have set `fork in IntegrationTest := true`, but test suites are always executed sequentially. According to the docs, this must not be the case: test suites should be executed concurrently.

the test suites are a class as following:

```
class MyTestSuite1 extends FlatSpec with Matchers 
...
it should "do A" {}
it should "do B" {}
```

```
class MyTestSuite2 extends FlatSpec with Matchers 
...
it should "do C" {}
it should "do D" {}
```

### the problem

MyTestSuite1 and MyTestSuiteN are executed sequentially (by the alphabet order to be exact)

### expectation

MyTestSuite1 and MyTestSuiteM are executed concurrently

### env

.sbopts:

```
-J-Xms1G
-J-Xmx4G
-J-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
-J-Xss4M
```

### note

I noticed that all test are running using the same pool and thread, for example, `pool-1-thread-1` for all tests.

sbt version: 1.2.8
Scala: 2.12.8
os: MacOS 10.15, Ubuntu 19.04
Scalatest ver: 3.2.0-SNAP10

Tried sbt v. 1.3.2 - same result.
Adding

```
testOptions in IntegrationTest += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-P4"),
```

does not help.

============

### Update

`fork in(IntegrationTest, test) := true` works on a global level, but I have 2 projects and I want to make it work to preserve relative path to the proj.

e.g.

```
lazy val `p1` = Project(id = "p1", base = file("./p1"))
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(Defaults.itSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    fork in(IntegrationTest, test) := true,
    ...)

lazy val `p2` = Project(id = "p2", base = file("./p2"))
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(Defaults.itSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    fork in(IntegrationTest, test) := true,
    ...)
```

does not run tests in parallel

instead, this runs in parallel, but, obviously, the home dir is set to be "." rather than to be "./p1" or "./p2" respectively:

```
fork in(IntegrationTest, test) := true

lazy val `p1` = Project(id = "p1", base = file("./p1"))
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(Defaults.itSettings: _*)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Nik, does this seem relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15753250/98057

Comment: hello, no, I think these are separate issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### SOLUTION:

It appears there's `testForkedParallel in IntegrationTest := true` option which does exactly what I needed - it spawns new JVM per test suite.

==============

### Remark:

So, the only problem is that now it spawns JVMs as many as the count of all available CPUs and I can't funnel only test concurrency:

OPTION 1 - funnels all sbt processes to be only 4 in parallel

```
concurrentRestrictions in Global := Seq(Tags.limitAll(4))
```

OPTION 2 - just does nothing (test are in the subproject)

```
concurrentRestrictions in Global += Tags.limit(Tags.Test, 4),
```

Answer (score 2):

By default tests executed in forked JVM are executed sequentially. Refer the following para from sbt testing docs:

> The setting:
>
> Test / fork := true
>
> specifies that all tests will be executed in a single external JVM.
>   See Forking for configuring standard options for forking. By default,
>   tests executed in a forked JVM are executed sequentially. More control
>   over how tests are assigned to JVMs and what options to pass to those
>   is available with testGrouping key.

So, you have two options:

1. Do not fork JVM and your tests will run parallelly by default
2. If you want to fork and still rut tests parallelly go through this docs:
   https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#Forking+tests

Comment: i wanted to exec tests in parallel by suite, but sequentially inside of the suite.